# how to to send chat text outbound to an external app from whatsapp using share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

can we intent out chat text from whatsapp to an external app. I have noticed that we can do the same for audio and video.but I want to do same for text. Basically select a chat text press the share intent and send it out to an external app.
pls share your thoughts 
prem

Comment: It all revolves  around the basic understanding of how Intent works in Android. Intent is the only way to share your data across application either that is text or multimedia, the only thing which is important is that other application must be accepting the type of data you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WhatsApp Faq page on how to send text information to WhatsApp. Probably you can you use the same Intent type to listen for shared messages.

[WhatsApp Faq Page](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

[Receiving Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: actually that talks about receiving text but not sending out text ( chat text) from whatsapp to external apps. that is the feature i would like to have. whatsapp allows the same for video, audio and images

Comment: yes i know the page talks about sending intents to whatsapp. so in an ideal case you would need to create an intent with the specific type listed in the FAQ and that should work.